# False Positive - Tests should include assertions - S2699

Tags: sonarqube

We have a lots of code (not all) on which an issue gets reported for not having an assert but it does exist in the test method.

Example Code that gets the violation:

```
@Test
public void successfullValidation() throws ErrorInfo_Exception {
   AgencyInfoServiceResponse agencyResponse = new AgencyInfoServiceResponse();
   AgencyInfoServiceResponseHeader header = new AgencyInfoServiceResponseHeader();
   header.setCmdStatus("Success");
   header.setCmdType("response");
   agencyResponse.setAgencyInfoServiceResponseHeader(header);
   assertTrue(validator.validate(agencyResponse));
}
```

But if I pull out the validator into a variable and assertTrue the variable then the violation goes away.
The assertTrue import is: `import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;`

I am using SonarQube 6.4.0.25310 with SonarJava 4.10.0.10260.

Why is it saying I do not have an assert?

Comment: This should be covered. Latest version of SonarJava plugin is 4.11.0.10660. Could you try with it as well? Seems that the semantic engine is not able to resolve method `validator.validate()`. Are you sure bytecode of the `validator` class is provided for test sources during analysis? If the engine can not access resolve the `validator` type, it won't be able to resolve `asserTrue()` method as well.

Comment: Updated to version 4.11.0.10660  and the issue continues.  I will look closer to see if the bytecode is available but I don't see why it would not be.